# How to derive the solution for the SDE $dX_t = \theta(t)X_t dB_t$ from Itô's formula?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I want to show that the Itô-process

$$
Z_t = \text{exp}( \int_0^t \theta_s dB_s - \int_0^t \frac{1}{2} \theta_s^2 ds) $$

is a solution to the SDE

$$ dX_t = \theta(t)X_t dB_t$$

using Itô's formula,

$$ dg(t,B_t) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(t,B_t)dB_t + ( \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} (t,B_t) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2} (t,B_t))dt  $$

i.e, I want to find a function $g(t,x)$ s.t $ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(t,B_t) = \theta(t) g(t,B_t)$ and $ \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} (t,B_t) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2} (t,B_t) = 0$.

But I'm stuck. How do I proceed?

Comment: You need a slightly more general version of Ito's formula: $$dg(t,X_t)=g_t(t,X_t)\,dt+ g_x(t,X_t)\,dX_t+\frac{1}{2}g_{xx}(t,X_t)\,d\langle X\rangle_t\,.$$

Comment: BTW. Your $\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial\color{red}t^2} (t,B_t)\,dt$ should  be $\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2} (t,B_t)\,dt\,.$

Comment: Use Itô's lemma with $g(t,x) = \ln x$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Itô process given by $$dY_t = - \frac{\theta_t^2}{2} dt + \theta_t dB_t $$
Now, to derive the dynamics of $Z_t$ you can apply Itô's formula to the function $f(x) = e^x$. Indeed, $$dZ_t = df(Y_t) = \Big\{- \frac{1}{2} \theta_t^2e^{Y_t} + \frac{1}{2}\theta_t^2 e^{Y_t}   \Big\} dt + \theta_t e^{Y_t} dB_t = \theta_t e^{Y_t} dB_t = \theta_t Z_t dB_t$$
So, indeed $Z_t$ satisfies your SDE.